# Plots are not appearing in PDF after using Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

In general, Sweave is making great looking PDFs for me.

However, when I plot a histogram, it is not appearing in my PDF.

I have a bare bones Sweave document as follows.  I can't seem to isolate what is missing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<ReadOrder,tidy=TRUE,highlight=FALSE>>=

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat))
p <- p + geom_histogram()
p
@
```

(PS :  yes, I have the 'listings' package installed in my LaTex package!  And yes, the plot is being printed to the terminal.)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I provide small working examples with Sweave [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340472/r-sweave-not-interpreted-correctly-due-to-writing-style#453206) for interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Upgraded from a comment).

Try adding `fig=TRUE` in the chunk options. (You might need an explicit `print()` around the `p` in the last line of the chunk too ...) If you use `knitr::knit` instead of Sweave, you won't need either of those explicit specifications ...

Comment: This did the trick.  The addition of the fig=TRUE into the chunk options worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @MattO'Brien apparently you are using the chunk options of knitr instead of Sweave

Comment: I cannot get any plots with Sweave with this example, only gibberish like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340472/r-executable-code-in-latex-such-that-r-plots-to-latex), ideas?