# R Sweave not interpreted correctly due to writing style?

Tags: plot, sweave, rstudio

This case won't get correctly interpreted. I doubt it must be to do something with my writing style but I cannot notice what it is. You can run it with `R CMD Sweave Test.Rnw; pdflatex Test.tex` produces the Test.tex file and then compiling to Test.pdf.

What is causing the running to result into gibberish? Why are the Sweave blocks not properly interpreted?

Test.Rnw causing gibberish

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
.
\begin{figure}
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   <<>>=
    all.lab <- c("Arr./A", "Sin", "Digox")
    all.dat <- c(2274959, 1531001, 2406739)
    barplot(all.dat,
            names.arg=all.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   %\includepdf{fig1.pdf}
   \caption{a}
   \label{fig:Ng1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   <<>>=
    age.lab <- c("Arr. +65", "Arr. [45,65]", "Arr", "Sin", "Sin +33")
    age.dat <- c(2274959, 1481397, 773624, 874208, 1087411)
    barplot(age.dat,
            names.arg=age.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   %\includepdf{fig2.pdf}
   \caption{b}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   %\includepdf{fig3.pdf}
   <<>>=
    gender.lab <- c("Arr. f", "A m", "Sin f", "Sinu", "Digox f", "Digon m")
    gender.dat <- c(1416043, 2448017, 1421385, 537783, 1256545, 1181350)
    barplot(gender.dat,
            names.arg=gender.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   \caption{c}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MAIN CAPTION}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to have something outside a float for it to compile. Put a dot before begin figure.

Comment: You also need to supply a mandatory argument to caption.

Comment: @Hugh I carried out the changes but the same error message stays: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 43--54
\T1/aer/m/n/10 names.arg=gender.lab, col="darkblue",
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\caption@ifstrut #1#2->#1
                         
l.56 \end
         {figure}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on....`

Comment: Use \caption{MAIN CAPTION} ie {} not [],  Then it compiles fine.  And the dot 'period' before \begin{figure} is not required.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved in the comments.

Comment: @Fran it is not solved in the comments, the same output stays, have you tried to run it?

Comment: @hhh Yes, It can compiled *as is* actually with RStudio, showing code and the figures, but instead of using Sweave, with the default knitr.  This way the chunk indentation and the lack of `fig=TRUE`  is not longer a  problem, the output is better (there are syntax highlight) and the only wrong (but not a fatal error) is use `\usepackage{Sweave}` that can be omitted using knitr as well as Sweave.

Comment: Anyway the result is not very good because you omit also `echo=FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The error is that you have indented the Sweave block, you must unindent the block. Sweave seems to be sensitive to indentation.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
all.lab <- c("Arr./A", "Sin", "Digox")
all.dat <- c(2274959, 1531001, 2406739)
barplot(all.dat,
    names.arg=all.lab,
    col="darkblue",
    ylab="Average byte size",
    xlab="Groups")
grid()
@
\caption{a}
\label{fig:Ng1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
age.lab <- c("Arr. +65", "Arr. [45,65]", "Arr", "Sin", "Sin +33")
age.dat <- c(2274959, 1481397, 773624, 874208, 1087411)
barplot(age.dat,
    names.arg=age.lab,
    col="darkblue",
    ylab="Average byte size",
    xlab="Groups")
grid()
@
\caption{b}
\label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
gender.lab <- c("Arr. f", "A m", "Sin f", "Sinu", "Digox f", "Digon m")
gender.dat <- c(1416043, 2448017, 1421385, 537783, 1256545, 1181350)
barplot(gender.dat,
    names.arg=gender.lab,
    col="darkblue",
    ylab="Average byte size",
    xlab="Groups")
grid()
@
\caption{c}
\label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MAIN CAPTION}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### **Minimal Working Examples**

The way I solved the issue was to encapsulate the issue, I noticed that there seems to be some conflicting character, block or space in the code. I provide below small working examples that made me realise that the error must be in the indentation.

**Example 1. OP's subcase working with Sweave**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)
all.lab <- c('Arr./A', 'Sin', 'Digox')
all.dat <- c(2274959, 1531001, 2406739)
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=all.lab, y=all.dat), stat='identity')
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Example 2. Ggplot working with Sweave**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{figure}
\centering
<<fig=TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat))
p <- p + geom_histogram()
print(p)
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Example 3. Base commands working with Sweave**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(1:10)
@
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Run**

1. R CMD Sweave test.Rnw
2. pdflatex test.txt
3. open test.pdf

Answer (score 2):

With Rstudio using `knitr`, your code *as is* can be compiled showing the plots, but you have to add `echo=FALSE` to hide the R code and fit the three images in a page. Of course, the `\usepackage{Sweave}` is not necessary (nor using Sweave with Rstudio). You can omit also any text outside the float.

If you need to stay with Sweave then  you should care of the chunk indentation, `fig=TRUE` option, and of course, at least for a float with three subfigures, omit the echo.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   <<echo=F>>=
    all.lab <- c("Arr./A", "Sin", "Digox")
    all.dat <- c(2274959, 1531001, 2406739)
    barplot(all.dat,
            names.arg=all.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   %\includepdf{fig1.pdf}
   \caption{a}
   \label{fig:Ng1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   <<echo=F>>=
    age.lab <- c("Arr. +65", "Arr. [45,65]", "Arr", "Sin", "Sin +33")
    age.dat <- c(2274959, 1481397, 773624, 874208, 1087411)
    barplot(age.dat,
            names.arg=age.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   %\includepdf{fig2.pdf}
   \caption{b}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   %\includepdf{fig3.pdf}
   <<echo=F>>=
    gender.lab <- c("Arr. f", "A m", "Sin f", "Sinu", "Digox f", "Digon m")
    gender.dat <- c(1416043, 2448017, 1421385, 537783, 1256545, 1181350)
    barplot(gender.dat,
            names.arg=gender.lab,
            col="darkblue",
            ylab="Average byte size",
            xlab="Groups")
    grid()
   @
   \caption{c}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MAIN CAPTION}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, `knitr` is more powerful: Just consider you "example 2" with knitr:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    <<>>=
        library(ggplot2)
        p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat))
        p <- p + geom_histogram(bins=30)
        print(p)
    @
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you compile knitr on commandline like Sweave? Or do you need Rstudio to run this? I found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/2956): `Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"
pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex` so it is similar, why would you use Knitr over Sweave?

Comment: @hhh Of course:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/11604

Comment: @Why knitr? Please my updated answer (but is not only for the syntax highlight, there are many advantages and many chunk options.)

Comment: It seems that knitr could be understood as a progression of Sweave while current new projects such Radix (built on Distill NPM/Node framework) built on top of Knitr? So if I want to visualise R results on the web, it seems that I could do that with Knitr and Radix?

https://rstudio.github.io/radix/

Comment: @hhh With knitr you can make LaTeX files that can produce a PDF or a web page,  or HTML page directly, or a markdown file that with pandoc could be in several formats. As far I saw Radix is only for markdow to produce web pages and it does not  depend on knitr.